# NSKeyedUnarchiver EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with protocol

Tags: swift, ios11, ios12, nskeyedunarchiver, ios13.2

I am updating my application to support IOS 11 versions
Currently it works on IOS 13.2
But on IOS 11 and IOS 12.2 I have EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObject

The class with the error

```
class Seance : NSObject, NSCoding{
  var date: NSDate
  var action: [String:ObjectifData] = Seance.actionStartupPoint()
  var duration = 0.0
  static var instance: Seance? = nil

static func actionStartupPoint() -> [String: ObjectifData]{
    var a: [String: ObjectifData] = [String:ObjectifData]()
    for objectif in Storage.instance.objectif{
        a[objectif.key] = objectif.value.type.initialise
    }
    return a;
}


init(date: NSDate){
    self.date = date;
}

required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
    self.date = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "date") as! NSDate
    self.action = try decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "action") as! [String: ObjectifData] // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ERROR
    self.duration = decoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "duration")
}
func encode(with coder: NSCoder){
    print(action)
            print(date)
                    print(duration)
    coder.encode(date, forKey: "date")
    coder.encode(action, forKey: "action")
    coder.encode(duration, forKey: "duration")
}

func convertActionToObjectifData() -> [String: Objectif]{
    var dic: [String: Objectif] = [:]
    for convert in action{
        if Storage.instance.objectif[convert.key] != nil {
            dic[convert.key] = Storage.instance.objectif[convert.key]!
        }
    }
    return dic
}
}
```

ObjectifData is Protocol with 3 parent

Like this

```
class BinaireData : NSObject, NSCoding, ObjectifData {

var validate: Bool = false

func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(validate, forKey: "validate")
}
override init(){}
required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    self.validate = decoder.decodeBool(forKey: "validate")
}


func getObjectifType() -> ObjectifType {
    return .binaire
}

func getPrimaryValue() -> Double {
    return validate ? 1 : 0
}

func stringFormatedValue() -> String {
    return validate ? "Oui" : "Non"
}
func updateFromWatch(message: [String : Any]) -> Bool {
    let value: Bool = message["event"] as! Bool
    if(self.validate != value){
        self.validate = value
        return true
    }
    return false
}
}
```

ObjectifData =

```
protocol ObjectifData: NSObject {

func getObjectifType() -> ObjectifType
func getPrimaryValue() -> Double
func stringFormatedValue() -> String
func updateFromWatch(message: [String:Any]) -> Bool}
```

And for load this I do this at startup

```
training = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! [String: [Seance]]
```

[Breakpoint Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AMUj.png)

after several research I noticed that it is possible that the problem occurs because of the protocols that are not allowed in the NSKeyUnarchiver on ios11

is it true ?
How can I fix the problem?
Thanks for reading
Have a good day

Comment: It’s more interesting how `ObjectifData` is defined.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for reply I have update post and add ObjectifData declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to encode and decode an object typed as `[String: ObjectifData]`, where ObjectifData is a protocol. You can't do that; a protocol is not a real type! I'm not surprised about the crash; I'm only amazed that this doesn't crash in iOS 13 as well.

Comment: Also, aren't you getting any warnings about not using NSSecureCoding here? You are crashing at a forced cast. If you used NSSecureCoding there would be no forced cast.

Comment: It surprises me too, but now I do not know how to convert my protocol so that it can be backed up on ios 12 or 11

Comment: To try I add  `archiver = NSKeyedArchiver.init(requiringSecureCoding: false)` but false or true is same

Comment: You can't "back up" a _protocol_. It isn't a thing. You need to use some other mode of expression entirely. You have not explained what this protocol is for. In your code, you have shown us only _one_ type (BinaireData) that adopts this protocol. That's silly. A protocol that is adopted by only one type is not a protocol at all; it can (and should) be thrown away with no loss of generality.

Comment: I used 3 different type 'TimeData' 'BinaireData' and 'CounterData' it's very useful in a dictionary, But maybe I'll have to do 3 different dictionary to save it independently.

Comment: Try superclass and subclasses instead. A superclass is a real type.

Comment: I tried to convert by subclassing it made me a lot of change and it works thank you very much and in addition I would have no problem of compatibility with the old system

Answer (score 0):

To be able to encode classes which adopt `ObjectifData` it must also be constrained to `NSCoding`

```
protocol ObjectifData: NSObject, NSCoding
```

Comment: I have add it but that do not work it give me same error

Comment: Add the Exception Breakpoint to get more information about the crash.

Comment: I see nothing https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AMUj.png can help you ?